# Как изменить дату последнего коммита Github?

Tags: github, git-commit, git-reset

1. Запушил коммит на Гитхаб.
2. Выяснилось, что он там совсем не нужен.
3. Удалил коммит командой `$ git reset --hard`
4. Затем отправил изменения `$ git push --force`
5. Коммит удалился, но дата последнего коммита осталась как до удаления. 
   Дату проверяю командой `$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{reponame}`.

Вопрос: как сместить дату последнего коммита обратно, на предыдущий коммит?

Comment: боюсь давать надоедливые комментарии, но что, если сделать удалённый пулл, и потом уже там посмотреть шоу

Comment: т.е., информация, возвращаемая приведённым вами запросом, не соответствует истине. [пишите багрепорт разработчикам api](https://github.com/contact).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Связался с [GitHub Support](https://github.com/contact):

> Date of the last commit didn't decreased after deleting last commit
>
> 1. Pushed commit.
> 2. Found out, that there was no need.
> 3. Deleted commit by `$ git reset --hard` and `$ git push --force`
> 4. Commit went away, but the date of `pushed_at` and `updated_at`, that I receive from `$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{reponame}` stays the same, as before deleting.
>
> Question: why don't I receive correct dates from api.github ?

Их ответ:

> The behavior you observed is expected. The `pushed_at` timestamp tells you the date of the last push, not the date of the last commit (as the name itself suggests). A push can add commits or it can remove commits -- but both are pushes. The `updated_at` timestamp tells you the date of the last update to the repository's record, which again isn't the date of the last commit.
>
> The best way to get the date of the last commit is to fetch that commit and then read the date from the commit information.

Получается, что `github` записывает все изменения `push`, а удаление коммитов - это тоже `push`.

`$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{reponame}` - возвращает сведения о последнем изменении репозитория.

`$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{reponame}/branches/{branchname}` -
возвращает сведения о последнем коммите ветки.

То есть в моем случае получается, что вместо 1 запроса теперь 2 писать надо. Первый для даты последнего коммита, а второй для `stargazers`. Раньше все в одном помещалось.